# Why Java Generic can't design to inherit to a parent Generic class?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

All, I may have a basic misunderstand about the Generic in Java ,

Why can't we write a Java Generic son class to inherit its parent Generic class ?

define such as :

```
public class JsonResponse<T> implements Response {
}
```

But I define a another son class to inherit it :

```
public class MeetingClientResponse<T> extends JsonResponse<T> {
}
```

I define another caller class as:

```
public interface HttpExecutor<T extends Response> {
}
```

impl it class is :

```
public class DefaultHttpExecutor<T extends Response> implements HttpExecutor<T> {
       public DefaultHttpExecutor(ResponseHandler<T> responseHandler) {
    this.responseHandler = responseHandler;

}
}

public class JsonResponseHandler<T> implements ResponseHandler<JsonResponse<T>> {
}

public class ScheduleMeetingResponseHandler extends
    JsonResponseHandler<ScheduleMeetingResponseVO> {
}

handler = ScheduleMeetingResponseHandler.newIntance()
```

When I use like this , it is no compile error:

```
HttpExecutor<JsonResponse<ScheduleMeetingResponseVO>> httpExecutor = 
new DefaultHttpExecutor
         <JsonResponse<ScheduleMeetingResponseVO>>(handler);
```

But When I use like this , it will compile error in Eclipse :

```
HttpExecutor<MeetingClientResponse<ScheduleMeetingResponseVO>> httpExecutor = 
new DefaultHttpExecutor
          <MeetingClientResponse<ScheduleMeetingResponseVO>>(handler);
```

Eclipse tip error as :  The Constructor DefaultHttpExecutor is undefined

Comment: Both of those declaration compiles fine on eclipse.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Could you specify the error you got in Eclipse?

Comment: The Constructor DefaultHttpExecutor is undefined

Comment: @JerryCai That error should have been shown for both of them, if only shown. How is your `handler` declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `DefaultHttpExecutor` constructor as

```
public DefaultHttpExecutor(ResponseHandler<? super T> responseHandler)
```

This is because you're trying to create a `DefaultHttpExecutor` for `MeetingClientResponse`, but you're passing to it a handler which is for `JsonResponse`.

With that declaration, you state that the executor will be able to work with a handler specific for `MeetingClientResponse`, or more generic handlers which can be satisfied with a supertype of the specific kind.

See also [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Answer (score 0):

The `DefaultHttpExecutor<T>` constructor expects a `ResponseHandler<T>` argument. More accurately, it expects an argument *declared* as a `ResponseHandler<T>`. So, you need to *declare* handler as a `ResponseHandler<MeetingClientResponse<ScheduleMeetingResponseVO>>` (or a sub type):

```
ResponseHandler<MeetingClientResponse<ScheduleMeetingResponseVO>> handler;
```

I emphasized the word *declare* because the declaration is what matters. If your handler is declared as a `ResponseHandler<JsonResponse<ScheduleMeetingResponseVO>>`, you get a compile error, even if you handler is in fact a `ResponseHandler<MeetingClientResponse<ScheduleMeetingResponseVO>>`.